# Struggle finding example and couter example of locally closed subspaces

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I'm come across the definition and examples of locally closed subset on wikipedia, but I can't get a grasp on the different examples given. Correct me if I'm wrong :

For the example of a locally closed subset we can take  $E = \left ] 0,1 \right ] =  \left ]0,2 \right [\cap  \left [ 0,1 \right ]$ because here for every $x$ of this subset, you can find a neighborhood $x$ which is basically a closed ball around $x$ included in the subset such that its intersection with $E$ is a closed subset of $E$.

While for the counter example : $E = \left\{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\mid x\neq0\right\}\cup\{(0,0)\}$ I don't understand why we can't for each $x$ in $E$ find with the method method a closed neighborhood $U$ of $x$ included in $E$ such that the intersection of $U$ and $E$ (which is equal to $U$) is closed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the point $x=(0,0)\in E$, $U\cap E=\{(x,y)\in U:x\neq 0\}\cup \{(0,0)\}$ and $U\setminus(U\cap E)=\{(x,y)\in U:x=0,|y|> 0\}$ which cannot be open in $U$.

A [neighborhood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_(mathematics)) of $x$ is a set whose interior contains $x$.

The wikipedia definition of locally closedness only assume the existence of a neighborhood $V$, but this is equivalent to existence of an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, since if $x\in U\subset V$ and $V\cap E$ closed in $V$, then $U\cap E$ closed in $U$.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand which neighborhood $U$ you've used ? In $(0,0)$, can I take the following neighborhood $\left [ -1,1 \right ]\times \left\{ 0\right\}$ which is closed in $U$ ?

Comment: A neighborhood is a set with the point $x$ in its interior, $\left [ -1,1 \right ]\times \left\{ 0\right\}$ is not a neighborhood of (0,0)

Comment: Oh yeah, I get it now, thank you very much.